# alias not recognized if alias command is piped to bash

Tags: bash

I want to execute a small script by piping it into bash to execute it remotely without the need to copy. Everything seems to work except aliases:

```
echo "alias test_alias=\"echo alias\"; test_alias" | bash
bash: line 1: test_alias: command not found
```

Does anyone know why this fails?

Comment: By default aliases are only expanded in interactive shells.

Comment: Use a function instead.

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense...